# Flutter Undo Delete Animation in Dismissable List

Tags: dart, flutter

I have created a List based on the Flutter swipe to dismiss example. I have been able to implement an undo in the snackbar which replaces the deleted item in the list in its original position. While I am happy with the functionality I don't like that the undo item snaps into place, how can I add an animation that would handle this making the undo look more elegant? I've had a look at the animation examples but I'm not sure how I apply it to the dismiss item list example (my code is virtually the same apart from the fact that I use a floating action button to open a dialog which saves the list item to the dismissable list)

Abu

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You may want to take a look at [AnimatedList](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html)